# BehaviorSubject not working as expected Angular

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I am trying to pass an email from accountrecovery component to password-reset component with BehaviorSubject but Im not receiving the email in password-reset component instead I get the initial value. I receive the new email in the service tho.

accountrecovery.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyseatDataService } from '../../storitve/myseat-data.service';
import { SendemailbetweencompService } from '../../storitve/sendemailbetweencomp.service';
@Component({...})
export class AccountRecoveryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myseatdata: MyseatDataService,
              private givemailtopasscomp:SendemailbetweencompService) { }

  public resetEmailData = {email: ""}
  public sendEmailData(): void {
    this.givemailtopasscomp.sendMail(this.resetEmailData.email);
    //... do backend
  }
}
```

sendemailbetweencomp.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SendemailbetweencompService {
    private emailsource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('test@gmail.com');
    emailsource$ = this.emailsource.asObservable();

    constructor(){ }
    sendMail(email: string){
        this.emailsource.next(email); //console.log(this.emailsource.getValue()); value arrives here
    }
}
```

password-reset.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyseatDataService} from '../../storitve/myseat-data.service';
import { SendemailbetweencompService } from '../../storitve/sendemailbetweencomp.service';
@Component({...})
export class PasswordResetComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myseatdata: MyseatDataService,
              private givemailtopasscomp: SendemailbetweencompService) { }

  public resetPassword(): void {
    this.givemailtopasscomp.emailsource$.subscribe( email => {
      console.log(email); // returns test@gmail.com instead of a new value
    });
    // do backend
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.givemailtopasscomp.emailsource$.subscribe( email => {
      console.log(email); // returns test@gmail.com instead of a new value
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: is `SendemailbetweencompService ` listed in providers anywhere?

Comment: Please share a minimal Stackblitz

Comment: @Andrei No but it has this @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

Comment: @T.SunilRao I re created it in Stackblitz but its working fine, I still dont know what the problem is in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [quick example](https://angular-ivy-supclf.stackblitz.io) to how to use a service to pass data to another component.

First create a service that contains a `Subject` (here your `BehaviorSubject`).
Then in your emitter component, inject this service and pass the password in the subject via `.next()` method.
In the destination component, inject the service and bind your password property to the subject.